# How to cluster all Markers except one

Tags: react-native, react-native-map-clustering

i am using [react-native-map-clustering](https://github.com/venits/react-native-map-clustering) for clustering Markers on the google map. All of Markers are dynamic except one, which indicates my location. When i zoom out map clusters all Markers. But i want something like this
[image]
Here is my implementation:

```
<MapView
            layoutAnimationConf={LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut}
            animationEnabled={true}
            ref={mapRef}
            style={styles.map}
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            initialRegion={currentRegion}
            // region={currentRegion}
            clusteringEnabled={true}
            radius={70}
            customMapStyle={mapConfig}>
            <Marker coordinate={currentRegion} title={'my location'}>
                <Image
                    source={images.currentLocation}
                    style={{
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                    }}
                />
            </Marker>
            {branchMarkers()}
        </MapView>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the ***cluster*** prop on the Marker to ***false*** like so:

```js
<Marker
  coordinate={coordinate}
  cluster={false}
  ...
/>
  <Image ... />
</Marker>
```

This will keep this one Marker permanently declustered and visible on the map at all zoom levels, not affecting other clusters. Internally, for each *Marker* which is a child of the *MapView*, a check if that *Marker* should be included in a cluster is done in a [helper function](https://github.com/venits/react-native-map-clustering/blob/master/lib/helpers.js#L6) that checks if this prop has been overridden:

```js
export const isMarker = (child) =>
  child &&
  child.props &&
  child.props.coordinate &&
  child.props.cluster !== false;
```

Note for TypeScript users:

react-native-map-clustering does not export a *Marker* component with a defined *cluster* prop. Applying cluster prop to a *Marker* imported from react-native-maps will trigger a ts compiler error, so you'd need to define your own Marker type or ignore this ts error.

Comment: How would you define your own Marker type?

Comment: cluster property is not found!